# i can't find any problem but it is not working

Tags: python

```
import random
x = random.randint(1,100)
y = int(input('write your number: '))
while y > x:
    print('my number is smaller')
    y = int(input('write your number: '))
while y < x:
    print('my number is bigger')
    y = int(input('write your number: '))
while y == x:
    print('your right')
    break
```

my problem in this code is when i enter a 4 or 5 number the program will shut without any response i tried to change last while to if and erase break but it didn't work some times thanks for helping

Comment: Your code assumes that the guess may be too high, then too low, then correct. What if the first guess is too low and the second is too high?

Comment: Your - belonging to you. You’re - you are.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right explanation are given by @TimRoberts and @Barmar. I have nothing to add but just an advice: before coding, you have to think about your algorithm. At the end, this is not a problem of coding in Python.

```
import random
x = random.randint(1,100)

while True:
    y = int(input('write your number: '))
    if y > x:
        print('my number is smaller')
    elif y < x:
        print('my number is bigger')
    else:
        print('your right')
        break
```

To be more Pythonic, you have to test if the user inputs a number. Use a try/except block like this:

```
import random
x = random.randint(1,100)

while True:
    try:
        y = int(input('write your number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('your input should be a number')
        continue
    if y > x:
        print('my number is smaller')
    elif y < x:
        print('my number is bigger')
    else:
        print('your right')
        break
```

Comment: Your code is virtually the same, except that you print the right answer to begin with, which kind of defeats the purpose...

Comment: @TimRoberts We humans need all the help we can get to avoid being overthrown by robots.

Comment: I forgot the `continue` statement. Thanks you @khelwood

Answer (score 0):

You should not have separate `while` loops for each condition. What happens if you enter a higher number in the second loop? You won't go back to the first loop.

Use a single loop and test each condition with `if`, not `while`.

```
import random
x = random.randint(1,100)
while True:
    y = int(input('write your number: '))
    if y > x:
        print('my number is smaller')
    elif y < x:
        print('my number is bigger')
    else:
        print("you're right")
        break
```

Comment: I think this is funny -- three identical answers within 20 seconds of each other.

Comment: @TimRoberts. I removed the `print` and added a `try/except` block to help OP.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the way your code flows.  If the person guesses too low, it will never again go back and check for too high.  You need the loop at the outermost level.

```
import random
x = random.randint(1,100)
while True:
    y = int(input('write your number: '))
    if y > x:
        print('my number is smaller')
    elif y < x:
        print('my number is bigger')
    else:
        print("you're right")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

x = random.randint(1,100)
y = int(input('write your number: '))

while y != x:
    if y > x:
        print('my number is smaller')
    if y < x:
        print('my number is bigger')
    y = int(input('write your number: '))

print('you are right')
```

Comment: You break the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle of development using 2 input.

Comment: true, but I think this example is easier to understand and follow for a beginner who is struggling with logic errors